# Stochastic processes with same distribution, which are no modification

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider stochastic processes $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$. How can I find an example in which $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ having the same distribution but are no modification of each other? I think I understood the concept of modification. But how do I find the distributions for $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$? I know that there can be defined a distribution by kolmogorov's extension theorem, but I wonder how this should look like. Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let X be a stationary Gaussian process with a given power spectrum.  Let Y be another stationary Gaussian process with the same power spectrum.  They meet your requirement.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If $(B_t)_t$ is a Brownian motion, you can consider $X_t = B_t$ and $Y_t = - B_t$.